# Find divisors using congruences

Tags: modular-arithmetic, factoring

We have $n := 115921$       , $2^{\frac{n-1}{4}} \equiv 963 \pmod{n}$, and $2^{\frac{n-1}{2}} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. How would you calculate a divisor of $n$ and why will the method work correctly (without using any computational tool)?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  $n\mid963^2-1=962\times964$, so any prime factor of $n$ is a factor of $962$ or $964$

Comment: @AnotherUser thanks for the recommendations, I will improve my next questions! :)

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I arrived at the same conclusion but wasn't sure if that is correct, thanks a lot!